# Perl : Ignore first line, while reading per character of file

Tags: perl, file, parsing, character

I'm trying to read a file that looks like this:

```
> SOME HEADER
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
QRSTUPWXYZ123456
```

I need to be able to read the characters A,B,C,D etc..per character, so I'm using this loop:

```
while (read $file, my $char, 1){


  print $char;
  print $.;

  print "\n\n";
}
```

But the problem is, I need to skip the "SOME HEADER". I need to skip it not on the basis of it being the first line, but on the basis of having a "> SOME HEADER" substring.

printing the $. always outputs "6" even though it's not the correct line number.

Comment: Clearly, you'll need to keep a buffer and check it for that substring, to throw it away (clear the buffer).  OR -- read by line, check for the substring and skip, or process the string with line by char if that's what you need ... so, why do you read by character?  What do you need to do?

Comment: The [`$.` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) doesn't work for `read`

Answer (score 0):

```
open my $file,"<","file.txt";
<$file>; #Removing first line
while (read $file, my $char, 1)
{
    print $char;
}
```

Or set the flag and check it

```
my $flag = 0;
while (read $file, my $char, 1)
{
    $flag = 1 and next if(($char =~m/\n|\r\n/) && ($flag == 0));
    next if $flag == 0;
    print $char;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to process line-by-line and *then* character-by-character?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^> SOME HEADER/;

    for my $char (split(//)) {
        print "$char $.\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
> SOME HEADER
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
QRSTUPWXYZ123456
```

Output:

```
A 2
B 2
C 2
...
4 3
5 3
6 3
```

Comment: Just a thought: what if the file is 100 MB and only one line